# Loading Raster with SharpMap (GDAL) doesn't work

Tags: gdal, c#, sharpmap

I have problems loading rasterfiles (.tiff) with SharpMap

I tried initializing a SharpMap GDAL Layer but nothing happens. It doesn't even throw and error when debugging after I set a path for the file which doesn't even exist.

```
SharpMap.Layers.GdalRasterLayer G = new 
SharpMap.Layers.GdalRasterLayer("Raster", "C:\\*.tiff");
```

I have all the gdal.dll linked in my Visual Studio Project.

Since I also have a world file for my raster (.tfw) I also tried using a GdiImageLayer, which can optionally use a world file https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpMap/

```
 SharpMap.Layers.GdiImageLayer H = new SharpMap.Layers.GdiImageLayer("Raster", "C:\\*.tiff");
```

but how can I set it?

Sorry for my bad English and being completely new to C# programming.

Comment: Please help me. BTW. Im using VS 2013 :(

Comment: Okay guys, i solved this problem by using NuGet manager to install packages for my project. I think by downloading the .dll on my own i must have put them in the wrong directories.